# How to make matching fields (in unrelated records) trigger workflow?

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have professional edition, but we have access to workflows.  I would like to trigger a workflow when two contacts in our org have matching email addresses, phone numbers, or names. Any suggestions for how I might do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in PE you are somewhat limited. When Contact2 is inserted/updated, that event can fire a workflow. But the workflow has in scope only the values of Contact2, not all other Contacts.

EE and above orgs would traditionally solve this with a trigger on Contact and there are cookbook examples of how to that [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/preventing-duplicate-records-from-saving)

That said, in the aforementioned resource, there is a clever workaround by using shadow copies of the Contact.email, Contact.phone, etc. wherein you use Unique custom fields to enforce uniqueness.

However, the boys and girls at SFDC have just introduced in Winter 15 (and PE is supported) - Duplicate Management. You can read about it [here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_sales_dedupe_intro.htm)  Contacts are one of the objects supported.  I'd look seriously at this.